# React star rating not working as expected

Tags: css, reactjs, rating-system

I'm trying to implement a star rating system provided by react. I'm referring this article to do this.

```
http://cameronroe.github.io/react-star-rating/?react-star-rating=4
```

**my star rating jsx file**

```
import React from 'react';
import StarRating from 'react-star-rating';

class FormComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (

            <StarRating name="airbnb-rating" totalStars={5}/>
        );
    }
}
export default FormComponent;
```

I'm calling it like this

```
<div className="preview_usr_stars">

    <FormComponent/>

</div>
```

But I get a result like this. Hover effects are not working, basically it does not work

[image]

Comment: Could you show us how you render the component?

Comment: I have shown it

Comment: I mean just put it inside a  `div` won't actually render it?

Comment: most probably the issue of not including the css file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not included the CSS.

From the link you provide:

```
Include the css:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/react-star-rating/dist/css/react-star-rating.min.css">
```

If you are using webpack with `css-loader`, you can simply do

```
import 'react-star-rating/dist/css/react-star-rating.min.css'
```